# How to delete database tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have created some databases with postgres, and put some data in them.

The problem is when I delete/drop database, and then create new database, the new database always contains tables and data from the first database that was created with postgres.

How can I delete database so that, when the new database is created it dosent contain data from old database?

Thanks

Comment: @BurhanKhalid in pgAdmin I go to [name](localhost:5432) right click and the select Delete/Drop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you created tables in the template1 database (or you specify the `TEMPLATE xyz` option with your `CREATE DATABASE` statement).

To get rid of the tables in the template1 database, connect to it and drop all tables there. After that new database will not contain those tables any more.

Comment: Yep, or just connect as user `postgres` to the `postgres` db and `DROP DATABASE template1;` then `CREATE DATABASE template1 TEMPLATE template0`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the rows in table using truncate commnad

```
 truncate <tablename>
```

then delete database using drop command

```
drop database <databasename>
```